# Unable to create dataframe from RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a recommender system from this kaggle dataset: f7a1f242-c

https://www.kaggle.com/kerneler/starter-user-artist-playcount-dataset-f7a1f242-c

the file is called: "user_artist_data_small.txt"

The data looks like this:

1059637 1000010 238

1059637 1000049 1

1059637 1000056 1

1059637 1000062 11

1059637 1000094 1

I'm getting an error on the third last line of code.

```
!pip install pyspark==3.0.1 py4j==0.10.9
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext 
appName="Collaborative Filtering with PySpark"
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,IntegerType,StringType,LongType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount ('/content/gdrive')

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(appName).getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

userArtistData1=sc.textFile("/content/gdrive/My Drive/data/user_artist_data_small.txt")


schema_user_artist = StructType([StructField("userId",StringType(),True),StructField("artistId",StringType(),True),StructField("playCount",StringType(),True)])

userArtistRDD = userArtistData1.map(lambda k: k.split())

user_artist_df = spark.createDataFrame(userArtistRDD,schema_user_artist,['userId','artistId','playCount']) 

ua = user_artist_df.alias('ua') 
(training, test) = ua.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])  #Training the model
als = ALS(maxIter=5, implicitPrefs=True,userCol="userId", itemCol="artistId", ratingCol="playCount",coldStartStrategy="drop")

model = als.fit(training)# predict using the testing datatset

predictions = model.transform(test)
predictions.show()
```

The error is:

```
IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column userId must be of type numeric but was actually of type string.
```

So I change the type from StringType to IntegerType in the schema and I get this error:

```
TypeError: field userId: IntegerType can not accept object '1059637' in type <class 'str'>
```

The number happens to be the first item in the dataset. Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a dataframe using the CSV reader (with a space delimiter) instead of creating an RDD:

```
user_artist_df = spark.read.schema(schema_user_artist).csv('/content/gdrive/My Drive/data/user_artist_data_small.txt', sep=' ')
```